# Proper way to call .env file inside project

Tags: php, environment-variables, phpdotenv

I wanted to see what would be the proper way to call a `.env` file inside my project? One of the developers that I'm working with, just told me that everything is setup and that all I would need is to create a `.env` file in the root.

Here is how the function is being called:

```
$settings = [
    'name' => 'DB_NAME',
    'user' => 'DB_USER',
    'password' => 'DB_PASSWORD',
    'host' => 'DB_HOST',
];
```

I have my `.env` file setup as the following (I've created the local database using the below credentials):

```
cc
cc_user
Z_______0!
localhost
```

Is this the correct method? Do I need quotes around the name, user, password and host inside the `.env` file? I am doing all this on a localhost environment.

Comment: I find the misused `javascript` tag very concerning here. Surely the file you're looking at has a `.php` extension and is more than enough information to tell you what language you're using...

Comment: PHP does not natively load `.env` files, and as such we can only speculate as to what the format is supposed to be. You should ask your coworker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.env` file should look like this:

```
DB_NAME=cc
DB_USER=cc_user
DB_PASSWORD=Z_______0!
DB_HOST=localhost
```

You don't need quotes here

Comment: What a simple and effective answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to set up your .env file with KEY=value pairs, something like

```
DB_NAME='mydatabase'
```

Your code sample doesn't give enough to know for sure, but the first thing that comes to mind for me is npm's dotenv package, documentation for which can be found here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: He is not working with npm? Sp npm dotenv link is not suitable. [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

Comment: The question was originally tagged for Javascript, hence the reason I went in that direction.

Comment: where can I find the .env file in my project ?

Comment: You usually have to create it in the project root